# CharIndex to select rows with full word search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written the following SQL query. I wanted to return only "New York" and "New Jersey". But my data set returns "New" along with it.

Query:

```
DECLARE @charToSerch nvarchar(100)

SET @charToSerch='New York,New Jersy'

Create table #Temp
(
        Name nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT into #temp(Name) values('New')
INSERT into #temp(Name) values('New York')
INSERT into #temp(Name) values('New Jersy')
INSERT into #temp(Name) values('Dellas')
INSERT into #temp(Name) values('Laligam')

Select * FROM #temp where charindex(Name,'New York,New Jersy')>0

DROP table #temp
```

And data set is shown as follows.

```
Name
---------
New
New York
New Jersy
```

Please help me to short out this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function to split a string into rows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_SplitIntoTable](@String varchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))     
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items varchar(500))     
AS     
BEGIN     
    DECLARE @idx int     
    DECLARE @slice varchar(max)     

    SELECT @idx = 1     
        IF len(@String)<1 or @String is null  RETURN     

    WHILE @idx!= 0     
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)     
        IF @idx!=0     
            SET @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        ELSE     
            SET @slice = @String     

        IF(LEN(@slice)>0)
            INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) VALUES(LTRIM(RTRIM(@slice)))     

        SET @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK     
    END 

    /* удаляем повторяющиеся ключи */
    ;WITH CTE(N) AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY items ORDER BY items)
        FROM @temptable
    )
        DELETE CTE WHERE N>1;

RETURN     
END
```

And use it this way

```
Select *
FROM #temp t
     join dbo.uf_SplitIntoTable(@charToSerch,',') s on t.Name=s.items
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct sql i think is:

```
Select * FROM #temp where charindex('New York',Name)>0 or Charindex('New Jersy',Name)>0
```

Information about [Patindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)